# passing a control as a parameter

Tags: winforms, vb.net-2010

am working on a project where some forms will have duplicate methods of populating comboboxes. In the code snippet below, the fonts installed on a given pc are added as items to a combobox. How can I pass a parameter that is the actual combobox to fill? eg, AddFonts(combobox)

```
Private Sub AddFonts()
    'add the font names installed on this pc to the font name combo box
    ' Get the installed fonts collection.
    Dim allFonts As New InstalledFontCollection
    ' Get an array of the system's font familiies.
    Dim fontFamilies() As FontFamily = allFonts.Families

    ' Display the font families.
    For i As Integer = 0 To fontFamilies.Length - 1
        'figure our how to make the textbox passable as a paramter
        cbxTitleFonts.Items.Add(fontFamilies(i).Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the control as Control Datatype and cast it in the actual control in the function.

```
Public  Sub mycallingfunc()
    myfunc(textbox1)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub myfunc(ctrl As Control)
    Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I would use DirectCast but how is the parameter actually passed?

Comment: by name? eg if the combobox name was foo it would be myfunc(foo) in your example above?

Comment: Thanks Romil the code below is the solution when calling the sub like AddFonts(Me.combobox)